# How to insert into a table with character['] in the field (pymssql)

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm trying to populate my db from a csv file using python. 
Below is the code I use to populate my `sales` table:

```
import csv
import pymssql as psql

conn = psql.connect('localhost:8888', 'SA', 'superSecret','videogame')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
  IF OBJECT_ID('sales', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE sales

  CREATE TABLE sales
  (
    Id int,
    Name varchar(250),
    Platform varchar(250),
    Year int,
    Genre varchar(250),
    Publisher varchar(250),
    NA_Sales float,
    EU_Sales float,
    JP_Sales float,
    Other_Sales float,
    Global_Sales float
  )
""")
conn.commit()

with open ('./sales.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        row[1] = row[1].replace("'", "")
        row[5] = row[5].replace("'", "")
        data = tuple(row)
        query = 'insert into sales values {0}'.format(data).replace("N/A","0")
        print(query)
        cursor.execute(query)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

However, some of my data contains the character:(') (e.g. Assassin's creed)in their name column. This caused an error, as below:

```
insert into sales values ('129', "Assassin's Creed III", 'PS3', '2012', 'Action', 'Ubisoft', '2.64', '2.56', '0.16', '1.14', '6.5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 447, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:7119)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1011, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query (_mssql.c:11586)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1042, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query (_mssql.c:11466)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1175, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query (_mssql.c:12746)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1586, in _mssql.check_cancel_and_raise (_mssql.c:16880)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1630, in    _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException (_mssql.c:17524)
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (207, b"Invalid column name 'Assassin's   Creed III'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server    error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Is there any workaround for this other than manually update the row (e.g. `row[1] = row[1].replace("'","")`?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a proper *parameterized query*, like this:

```python
row = ["Assassin's", "N/A", 9]  # test data as list (e.g., from CSV)
data = tuple("0" if x=="N/A" else x for x in row)
print(data)  # ("Assassin's", '0', 9)
placeholders = ','.join(['%s' for i in range(len(data))])
query = 'INSERT INTO sales VALUES ({0})'.format(placeholders)
print(query)  # INSERT INTO sales VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
cursor.execute(query, data)
```

Comment: How would this generalize if, say, we wanted to do 1000 rows at a time? That is, we'd want to do something like `INSERT INTO sales VALUES (0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)...`?

Comment: Is that equivalent to the `VALUES(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)...` notation? Or is it executing a single `INSERT`?

Comment: @Adrian - By using Microsoft's ODBC driver for SQL Server and enabling `fast_executemany` on the cursor we get the equivalent of what you described (albeit not with a Table Value Constructor *per se*).

Comment: After spending an entire day getting pymssql connected, switching to a different connection paradigm seems like more work. I think I've got it working by making the shapes of the string and the parameter tuple correct. It's not quite as fast, but it's more robust to SQL injection, and I imagine it'll handle the single quotes correctly, now.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `'` with a `\'`, which should stop it crashing whilst preserving the apostrophe in your data:

```
with open ('./sales.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        row[1] = row[1].replace("'", "\'")
        row[5] = row[5].replace("'", "\'")
        data = tuple(row)
        query = 'insert into sales values {0}'.format(data).replace("N/A","0")
        print(query)
        cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: The problem is that you're escaping the character in Python, whereas the error is occurring in the SQL `INSERT` statement - that is, in the database. The usual way to escape a single quote is by doubling it: `''`, but this doesn't work, either.